# Link from archive-page.php to single-page.php

Tags: single, custom-post-type-archives

I have `archive-page.php`, where my custom posts are displayed. I want to put a link on my image, `<a href="" alt=""><img src="" alt=""></a>`, which leads to `single-page.php` for that particular post or product. How can I do that?

I have tried this:

```
<a href= "<?php get_the_permalink ();?>" alt=""><img src="" alt=""></a>
```

but it does not work. I don't know what to put in `functions.php` and in those pages: `archive-page.php` and `single-page.php`

Answer (score 1):

[`get_the_permalink()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_permalink/) doesn't `echo` anything. It just returns a string so that you can further manipulate it.

You need [`the_permalink()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_permalink/) instead, which will `echo` the link.

The difference used to be clear in the Codex but now, in the much inferior, "developer" code reference toward which WordPress is migrating it is not so clear.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by **[this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/212758/161501)**,

```
<a href= "<?php get_the_permalink ();?>" alt=""><img src="" alt=""></a>
```

should be

```
<a href= "<?php echo get_the_permalink ();?>" alt=""><img src="" alt=""></a>
```

OR

```
<a href= "<?php the_permalink ();?>" alt=""><img src="" alt=""></a>
```